# Calculate the percentage of consecutive values in data frame which are the same

Tags: python, pandas, series

**Motivation**

I have a data frame containing time series originated from various sensors which record : temperature, humidity, UV radiation, etc..

Some times the sensor is "stuck", meaning I get the same measure again and again.

for example :

```
temp    humidity
36.4    20.2
36.2    21.1
37.1    22.0
37.1    22.2
37.1    22.1
37.1    22.3
37.1    22.2
36.2    21.1
36.3    21.1
36.1    21.1
36.4    21.1
36.4    21.1
36.2    21.1
```

- You can see that in row number 3, The temperature sensor got stuck on 37.1 for 5 rows, and the humidity go stuck on 21.1 for 6 rows in the end.
- let's define "Stuck" as value repeats itself more the X time (something in the range of 5-20, not sure yet).

How can I calculate for each row the percentage of "stuck" data ?

For example the output in the last example should be:

```
temp = 5/13 * 100 = 38%
humidity = 6/13 * 100 = 46%
```

I can do it "manually" by using 2 for loops, I'm sure there's a better way using pandas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function using `itertools.groupby` to count number of identical consecutive items. Then filter by a given minimum count.

This works because `itertools.groupby` is an O(n) solution which groups consecutive items rather than forming groups in their entirety at the end.

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_stuck_count(x, n):
    lens = (len(list(j)) for _, j in groupby(x))
    return sum(i for i in lens if i >= n)

df_len = len(df.index)
temp_stuck_pct = get_stuck_count(df['temp'], 5) / df_len
humidity_stuck_pct = get_stuck_count(df['humidity'], 5) / df_len

print(temp_stuck_pct)      # 0.38461538461538464
print(humidity_stuck_pct)  # 0.46153846153846156
```

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, if the temp will return again to 37.1, the groupby will add it to the group, am I wrong ?

Comment: No, `itertools.groupby` only works on consecutive items (test it yourself!). Behaviour is very different to Pandas `groupby`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the index of the beginning of the stuck chunks ? to know that temperature stuck in row number 5

Comment: @OopsUser, It's possible. Here's a hint: in `get_stuck_count`, if you print `[len(list(j)) for _, j in groupby(x)]` you will get `[1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]`. You then need to sum cumulatively up to each number which is >=5. In Pandas you have `pd.Series.cumsum`, in NumPy you have `np.cumsum`, so there are lots of options. If you're still stuck, please feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: Does it support two columns groupby ?

Comment: @OopsUser, Sorry, I don't know what you mean. I suggest you have a go yourself, then post a new question if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [582]: def get_stuck_pct(df, col, r=range(5,20)):
     ...:     max_cnt = df.groupby((df[col] != df[col].shift()).cumsum()).size().max()
     ...:     if max_cnt in r:
     ...:         return '{}%'.format(int(max_cnt / df[col].size * 100))
     ...:     return '0%'
     ...: 
     ...: 

In [583]: get_stuck_pct(df, 'temp')
Out[583]: '38%'

In [584]: get_stuck_pct(df, 'humidity')
Out[584]: '46%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to get all duplicates and then average the sum of the max occurrences in the sequence.

```
dup  = df.temp.duplicated().astype(int) 
lst  = dup.groupby(dup.eq(0).cumsum()).cumsum().tolist()

print max(lst) / float(len(lst))
>>>0.384615384615
```